# Quantum mechanical elastic scattering by a potential and apparent clash with conservation laws

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, potential, scattering

Consider the quantum theory of elastic scattering of a nonrelativistic particle of mass $m$ by a potential $V(\vec r)$. It is assumed that the magnitude of the momentum of the scattered particle remains unchanged i.e. $|\vec p|=|\vec p'|$ while only the direction changes.

Now of course this potential $V(\vec r)$ must be supplied by another particle of mass $M$, say.
In a two-body elastic scattering of masses $m$ and $M$, the momentum conservation tells
$$\vec p+\vec P=\vec p'+\vec P'\tag{1}$$ and the energy conservation tells $$\frac{|\vec p|^2}{2m}+\frac{|\vec P|^2}{2M}=\frac{|\vec p'|^{2}}{2m}+\frac{|\vec P'|^{2}}{2M}.\tag{2}$$

If the mass $M$ were initially at rest in the lab-frame (i.e. $\vec P=0$), and $|\vec p|=|\vec p'|$, the energy conservation equation (2) readily gives $|\vec P'|=0$. With this, squaring the momentum conservation equation (1), and using $|\vec p|=|\vec p'|$ and $\vec P=0$, we get, $$\vec P'\cdot(\vec P'+2\vec p')=0.\tag{3}$$

This means either $\vec P'=0$ or $\vec P'=-2\vec p'$. The first solution, $\vec P'=0$, cannot be true because it implies $\vec p=\vec p'$ i.e. there is no scattering; the momentum of the scattered particle remains unchanged both in magnitude and direction. The second solution, $\vec P'=-2\vec p'$ also cannot be true because it clashes with $|\vec P'|=0$.

Where is the mistake? With $|\vec p|=|\vec p'|$ and $\vec P=0$, what is the recoil momentum of the particle of mass $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether in quantum or classical physics, when a model system is described with the purpose of explaining concepts, some non-realistic assumptions are made to simplify the exposition of the concept.

Typically, when a potential enters in the problem, it is automatically assumed that whatever causes it has an **infinite mass** (unless, of course, it is explicitly indicated that the potential is created by a specific object of given mass).

If you replace $M$ by $\infty$ in your equation (2) you get the expected result.

Comment: In the infinite M limit, the recoil momentum $\vec P'\neq 0$ but $\frac{|\vec{P}'|^{2}}{2M}\to 0$. Am I right?

Comment: @Solidification    Yes. $\vec P'=-2\vec p'$ but with infinite mass it does not transfer any energy to the potential.